# ATS (application tracking system): no recent experience for the position

Tags: resume, applications, hiring

I have got a view onto the corporate ATS output and its conclusions, and it seems the system bases its conclusions on the most recent job. This means that all the candidates with no relevant experience on the *last* job **will be** disqualified at the entrance.

For the candidate not having appropriate experience for the target job on current/last job, what would be the best:

1. omit current/last job completely, starting resume from the appropriate, but past experience (thus looking like currently not being employed);
2. put inappropriate jobs on the list at the beginning in chronological order, but just write several (special) words about the experience;
3. re-oder the experience, putting most appropriate experience at the top, and inappropriate at the bottom, thus breaking the chronology but having consistency in dates;

... anything else?

I am looking for practically tested information, not a common sense how it may be.

Comment: Practically tested information requires the specific applicant tracking system. Which one are they using?

Comment: If this is a commonly used ATS, I wonder how it contributes to long term underemployment if people have to take a retail job to survive a layoff.

Comment: @MatthewGaiser On spot. I have only this information from the person using the system: "I passed your resume through the very same software that Hiring Managers use to filter the real talent from the hundreds, sometimes thousands, of candidates that apply for a single open position". I suspect the system used is Taleo. However insights to other systems will also be helpful.

Comment: Do you have the job application link? I can probably tell from the posting which one it is.

Comment: Or any job from that company if you want to be more private.

Comment: @MatthewGaiser for example Siemens: https://jobs.siemens-info.com/healthineers/jobs?page=1. But the impression I had is of unknown to me system, actually used by the topresume.com which checkmark I ticked on some site to have resume reviewed.

Comment: You are right. That is definitely Taleo.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because specific advice on how to cheat a specific applicant tracking system is not a generally useful workplace question and is also ethically dubious.

Comment: I am voting to delete this question. The answer and some comments were useful for me, and I found important piece of information there.

Comment: @Joe having robot evaluating people (read: AI) is ethically dubious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO,

What you have seen in one particular place is not necessarily industry wise.

But, resume should be updated according to every job you apply for.

Skills and Experience, requested in the job posting - should you have them, HAVE to be front and center in your resume sent for that position.

HR , recruiter, potential employer should not have to scroll through your resume to find your particular experience.

> put inappropriate jobs on the list at the beginning in chronological
>   order, but just write several (special) words about the experience;

This is not inappropriate job if it is on the money with what they are looking for.
it should be in the clause prior to experience timeline with header, relevant skills and experience on the first page in the center, maximum at the end of first page

Comment: Thank you. My question was more on ATS - electronic recruiter, rather than a human. Let's give you an example: an individual was head of accounting, then had to move to receptionist job. 2 years have passed, and she is applying for head of accounting at another firm. Should she put receptionist job in, where should she put it to get through ATS?

Comment: IMHO, receptionist job is not to be on the resume for accounting, due to its being irrelevant to position, applied for.  The gap should be explained in the side note or in the objectives section.  But the gap is still exist and her skills would be 2 years out of date. Unless as receptionist she did some accounting , then accounting skills should be front and center in the receptionist job outline